# Handling of XML elements with different name but similar structure using JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I have a XML file with elements having different names but similar structure(same attributes and child elements). I want to convert XML file to Java objects. I have used @XmlAnyElement annotation and it gives the element but it is not convertible to the Java object class. Through eclipse debugging I have verified that it is in the form ElementNSImpl which cannot be cast to the Object class.

Sample XML structure is following,

```
<element1 attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">
    <childElement1>
    <childElement2>
</element1>
<element2 attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">
    <childElement1>
    <childElement2>
</element2>
```

I am using JAXB annotations.

Answer (score 0):

**Root**

In JAXB Java classes correspond to complex types in XML Schema.  If `element1` and `element2` have the same type then they refer to the same class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    private Element element1;

    private Element element2;

}
```

**Element**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attr1;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attr2;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String attr3;

    private String childElement1;

    private String childElement2;

}
```

Comment: I know that XML structure will be same but I am not aware of the name of the elements.